# vision.VideoPlayer embedding in GUIDE created GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface, image-processing, matlab-guide, matlab-cvst

I'm trying to use the vision.VideoPlayer in a custom created GUIDE GUI. The video source is a camera. Right now I can get it to work with the camera but the vision.VideoPlayer object pops out of my gui. I've read the example given but it seems that this doesn't use the videoplayer rather than the videoreader object to read a video file and project the frames in a gui.

Is there any way to embed the vision.VideoPlayer in my GUI using input from a camera?

Comment: can you show some simple code that reproduces the problem?

Comment: There is no problem specifically.Just an random GUI from and a vision.VideoPlayer that can be fitted inside as Dima told below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to use `vision.VideoPlayer` in a custom GUI directly. However here an [example of how to play a video inside a custom GUI](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/video-display-in-a-custom-user-interface.html) without using `vision.VideoPlayer`.

Comment: I've seen this example.Unfortunately my supervisor insisted using vision.VideoPlayer.What is the best way to play a live video live form a  camera connected to a pc??

Comment: I am afraid you are going to have to tell your supervisor that `vision.VideoPlayer` can only run in its own separate window...

Answer (score 1):

I just uploaded this to the FEX:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/53600-fancyflowplayer

It uses no high level dependencies, only the "VideoReader" interface (which btw the vision.VideoPlayer also uses).

It is by no means a competitor to VLC(this IS Matlab we are talking about), but it is all open source and shows how you can access and process video in real-time. It also has a working draggable seekbar, extra keyboard and mouse interfaces that are really handy, which the vision.VideoPlayer does not have.

cheers,
Stefan